# Bootstrap table add row dynamically Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem about inserting a table row and I'm trying do something but it's not work efficiently. Can anyone help show me how to fix the add button with auto increment? 
 My simple code is as follows below. Thanks for any responses.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        margin: 100px;
    }

    table, td, th {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 10px;
    }

        table td.crossed {
            background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, transparent calc(50% - 1px), red, transparent calc(50% + 1px));
        }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <table id="t1">
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th><input style="margin-top:-200px; padding:10px" type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="add()" /></th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>1.</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="date" id="mydate">
        </td>
        <td contenteditable='true'></td>
        <td> <input type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow(this)" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created you a sample in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/973cg55m/1/) that is working. I created it while you were working on your sample, which coinsidently is actually working (though it adds an additional editbox no present in the first row template).

```
function createRowColumn(row) {
  var column = document.createElement("td");
  row.appendChild(column);
  return column;
}

function addRow() {
  var newrow = document.createElement("tr");
  var numericColumn = createRowColumn(newrow);
  var checkColumn = createRowColumn(newrow);
  var dateColumn = createRowColumn(newrow);
  var emptyColumn = createRowColumn(newrow);
  var removeColumn = createRowColumn(newrow);

  var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
  checkbox.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
  checkColumn.appendChild(checkbox);

  var datebox = document.createElement("input");
  datebox.setAttribute("type", "date");
  //datebox.setAttribute("id", "mydate"); //don't reuse id's
  dateColumn.appendChild(datebox);

  emptyColumn.setAttribute("contenteditable", "true");

  var remove = document.createElement("input");
  remove.setAttribute("type", "button");
  remove.setAttribute("value", "Delete Row");
  remove.setAttribute("onClick", "deleteRow(this)");
  removeColumn.appendChild(remove);

  var table = document.getElementById('t1');
  var tbody = table.querySelector('tbody') || table;
  var count = tbody.getElementsByTagName('tr').length;
  numericColumn.innerText = count.toLocaleString() + '.';

  tbody.appendChild(newrow);
}
```

Here is the sample you provided in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/du7L4fbr/1/) that seems to be doing fine on Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of debugging/trouble-shooting tips to help you figure out the answer on your own:

1. open up the console for your browser.  For example on chrome go to "more tools" -> "developer tools".
2. get a reference to the table you're trying to update:
   var table = document.getElementById("t1");
3. check it out (see what it looks like):

   `console.log ('table:',table);`
4. check out its properties:

   `for (var property in table){ console.log('property:', property); }`
5. it looks like you're referencing a javascript function that doesn't exist `deleteRow(..)`.  You might want to provide that function (just a stub initially) or remove that reference.